# Place a variable as a HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Basically, is it possible to do something like....

```
<a href=link onClick="clicked();">Click me!</a>

<script>
function clicked() {
    if(myVar == 1) {
        link="http://stackoverflow.com"
    }
    else if (myVar == 2) {
        link="http://google.com"
    }
}
</script>
```

This example is probably impossible due to it firing at the same time...
But is it at all possible to use variables there?

Basically, I need a link that'll bring you to two different places depending on a variable.
I suppose I could have two links, and just hide/show each one respectively depending on the variable, but I was wondering if it's possible another way?

I'm working with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and JQuery...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do...

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    if (condition) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = 'http://different-url.com';
    }
});
```

If the condition is met, then it will take you to a different URL.

Otherwise, the link will work as expected.

If you didn't want to use jQuery, that'd be...

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, anchorsLength; i < anchorsLength; i++) {
   anchors[i].onclick = function(event) {
      if (condition) {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.location = 'http://different-url.com';
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, I keep seeing `event.preventDefault();` -- what exactly does this "prevent" ?

Comment: @Johannes It prevents the default behaviour of the browser for that event.

Comment: Is there perhaps a place that lists browsers default behavior for events?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use Javascript to do a redirect:

```
<script>
function clicked() {
    if(myVar == 1) {
        window.location = "http://url1.com";
    }
    else if (myVar == 2) {
        window.location = "http://url2.com";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to do it the way you want.

Why don't you do this instead -

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="clicked();">Click me!</a>

<script>
function clicked()
{
    if(myVar == 1) 
    {
        window.location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
    else if (myVar == 2)
    {
        window.location.href = "www.google.com";
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for further references about the `window.location` object.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
<script> function clicked() {
    if(myVar == 1) {
        window.location="http://stackoverflow.com"
    }
    else if (myVar == 2) {
        window.location="http://google.com"
    } } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<a href=link onClick="clicked();">Click me!</a>

<script>
function clicked() {
    if(myVar == 1) {
        location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
    else if (myVar == 2) {
        location.replace("http://google.com");
    }
}
</script>
```

Cheers. This will take you to the desired place based on the myVar values!

Answer (score 0):

```
function clicked() {
    var dest = "";
    if(myVar) 
       dest = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    else
       dest = "http://google.com"
    window.navigate(dest);
```

But I see everyone said about the same. Just check which of the methods works on most browsers